# setPriority() method doesn't work properly

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I do the sample code from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/thread_getpri.htm). I get the result:

```
Thread[Thread-3,1,main]: 5
Thread[Thread-0,10,main]: 5
Thread[Thread-2,1,main]: 5
Thread[Thread-1,1,main]: 5
Thread[Thread-4,1,main]: 5
Thread[Thread-0,10,main]: 4
Thread[Thread-3,1,main]: 4
Thread[Thread-2,1,main]: 4
Thread[Thread-0,10,main]: 3
Thread[Thread-5,1,main]: 5
Thread[Thread-3,1,main]: 3
Thread[Thread-2,1,main]: 3
Thread[Thread-1,1,main]: 4
Thread[Thread-5,1,main]: 4
Thread[Thread-3,1,main]: 2
Thread[Thread-2,1,main]: 2
Thread[Thread-5,1,main]: 3
Thread[Thread-3,1,main]: 1
Thread[Thread-4,1,main]: 4
Thread[Thread-0,10,main]: 2
Thread[Thread-2,1,main]: 1
Thread[Thread-5,1,main]: 2
Thread[Thread-4,1,main]: 3
Thread[Thread-5,1,main]: 1
Thread[Thread-1,1,main]: 3
Thread[Thread-0,10,main]: 1
Thread[Thread-4,1,main]: 2
Thread[Thread-1,1,main]: 2
Thread[Thread-4,1,main]: 1
Thread[Thread-1,1,main]: 1
```

It seems that `setPriority` doesn't work properly. Why?

How can I modify the sample code to see the effect of property.

Comment: The `setPriority()` did work properly, you are observing the effects of a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) in printing the `toString()` method of each thread.

Comment: What kind of CPU do you have? Multi-core?

Comment: Yes, it's multi-core.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example you have found is broken.

- As other questions and comments have pointed out, if your JVM can use multiple cores, then multiple threads can run in parallel.  When that happens, it won't be just the highest priority runnable thread that run.
- On top of that, the behaviour of the thread scheduler with respect to priorities is dependent on the platform, not least because on a lot of platforms, thread scheduling is implemented by the OS rather than Java.

Here are some selected Oracle references that touch on thread priorities:

- [Recommended Coding Practices: Don't Depend on Thread Priorities](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13188_01/jrockit/docs142/devapp/codeprac.html#998533)
- [Java Threads Issues](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-3461/6jck06gqo/index.html) - which says:

  > The thread priorities available to Java threads on a native threaded JVM should be treated as hints to the scheduler, especially if the threads are compute-bound. The number of processors available to a process is dynamic and unpredictable. Therefore, an attempt to use priorities to schedule execution on any multi-tasked, multiprocessor system is not likely to succeed.

Apart from this kind of material, and material on how Java priorities map to native thread priorities, the Oracle documentation is pretty much silent on thread priorities for Java SE and what they mean.  Certainly, there is no attempt to specify the behaviour precisely.

Java RT (realtime) is a different issue, but that is no longer an Oracle supported product line.  (AFAIK).

Comment: "Java priorities map to native thread priorities..." and unless your program uses explicit RTOS system calls, the thread "priorities" are _not_ hard scheduling priorities.  In most non-real-time operating systems, "priority" really means scheduler bias.  The scheduler continually adjusts the _true_ priorities to insure that every thread that wants CPU time gets a _fair share_ of CPU time.  The scheduler bias (a.k.a., "priority" or, in Unix, "nice value") lets you say that this thread's fair share is larger or smaller than that thread's fair share.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've got a multi-core CPU.

Thread-priority only affects *thread scheduling*, i.e. it helps the system to decide, which threads to run next in case there are multiple threads waiting for execution.

But in your case, each thread is assigned to a different core. There are no waiting threads and *no scheduling is necessary*. All six threads really run in parallel and thread priority does not have any effect.

If you want to see the effect of thread priority, change the main method slightly to create enough high-priority threads to occupy all your CPU cores. Then, scheduling kicks in and thread priority plays a role:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        new SimplePriorities(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);

    // create enough high priority threads to occupy all CPU cores:
    for (int i = 0; i < Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(); i++)
        new SimplePriorities(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
}
```