# java : Is Thread priority changed by JVM(implicitly)

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-priority

When we create `new Thread(Runnable target)` It will have some priority as per parent thread.
My question is, can the priority be changed by the JVM in any circumstance?
I am not using *setPriority(int)* method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking whether the Thread scheduler **has** to schedule the threads according to their priority, the answer is **no**.

It can choose to do so (preemptive scheduling) but it's up to the platform to decide which scheduling algorithm to use.

Some readings:

- http://www.javatpoint.com/priority-of-a-thread
- [setPriority() method doesn't work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581057/setpriority-method-doesnt-work-properly)

Comment: I am not asking about scheduling. My question is simple  Thread priority can be change by the JVM or not

Comment: I think you gotta be precise on your question: what do you mean by "can JVM change it"?  Is it possible that someone write a JVM implementation is changing thread priority? Or is there any JVM implementation doing so?  I believe the spec does not forbid doing so (so probably Yes for first question), but I doubt if any JVM is doing that (so probably No for second question).  But, why would you care for this?

Comment: I am asking about regular JVM not overrided

Comment: The question wasn't clear to me, due to how you posed it. Why would the JVM change your priority when it can ignore it if it wishes to ? If you are given a setter, then you are the one in charge of setting something. As I said in my answer, it's the platform (usually the OS) that decides scheduling, which is what the priority tries to influence.

Comment: Then you can also post comment instead of post answer

Comment: I edited your question and, because you accepted it, I thought you agreed on my interpretation of your question. So I kept my answer. Anyway, I just wanted to give you my thought on the matter. Cheers.

Comment: @mcacorner If you're asking about thread priority you are asking about thread scheduling. Your quibble is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

No. It will not. Just to add, under the hoods, its the OS or System which has the final call on which threads to run on it's core and thus, its own scheduling algorithm is what eventually matters.

JVM however, presents the threads to OS and here the priority plays a role again based on JVM scheduling algorithm but its the OS which decides.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any explicit guarantees for this, but it isn't the sort of thing that is granted explicit guarantees.

There is a getter and setter for priority, and the implication is that the value won't change unless someone calls the setter again.

But please note this doesn't mean that no part of the system is allowed to call `setPriority()` on "your" threads, just that there is no internal trickery within the `Thread` class itself.